# /bin/gradle: 23: cd: can't cd to /bin/../share/gradle/bin/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Error after installation of gradle using "sudo apt-get install gradle" on ubuntu 20.04:

/bin/gradle: 23: cd: can't cd to /bin/../share/gradle/bin/..

Same issue for ant after "sudo apt-get install ant":

/bin/ant: 1: cd: can't cd to /bin/../share/ant/bin/..

Second case can be avoided by setting ANT_HOME for example using etc/ant.conf.
But gradle tries to set APP_HOME without looking any config.
How such an error can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Symlink is missing due to a bug in that version.
To fix the link:
`ln -snf /usr/share/ant/bin/ant /bin/ant`

Answer (score 1):

In my case `ls -al $(which gradle)` returned the following:

```bsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dez 10  2019 /bin/gradle -> ../share/gradle/bin/gradle
```

so it points to non-existing `/share/gradle/bin/gradle`.

```bsh
sudo rm /bin/gradle
sudo ln -s /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle /bin/gradle
```

resolved it here¹.

1): Linux Mint 20.2

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the error

```
/bin/ant: 1: cd: can't cd to /bin/../share/ant/bin/..
```

on Ubuntu 20.04.  Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10 fixed it for me.